# Multiple Animations in Parallel

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am now using the AnimationDrawable to change around 15 images on onCreate using onWindowFocus()Method.
I am also using translation animation in anim for translating image from one point to another.

I am now trying to execute both in parallel(change drawables according to the translation ) but it changes drawable only after the translation animation
please help..

final Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);
        a.reset();

```
    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

 iv.startAnimation(a);


iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_list);
  iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



   iv.setAnimation(a);



   a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_list);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
   a.startNow();



}

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)
    findViewById(R.id.imageView1).getBackground();
    if (hasFocus) {
        loadingAnimation.start();
    } 
    else {
        loadingAnimation.stop();
    }
}
```